# -bash: npm: command not found macOS Sierra

Tags: macos, npm

The file is in my Path so I don't know why its not working

> Hungs-MacBook-Pro-2:~ hungcao$ echo $PATH
>       /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/hung 1/.rvm/bin

I did sudo nano `/etc/paths`, and it shows

```
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

install it with brew, did you tried ? 
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
also can use nvm to run different versions of node.